# How can i call a controller method from view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have some requirement like, i need to create a jquery grid.I created the JQgrid, for that JQgrid i need to get some dynamic values from the controller method That method may return int or string (not an another view).When i am calling the controller method using @Url.Action("method", "controller").I am not getting value and that code part is not executing.

```
    function setrownumJQ() {
        var rownum = 0;
        rownum = '@Url.Action("method", "controller")';
        return rownum;
    }
Method in controller:


int setRowNum()
        {
           var r = 4;
            return r;
        }
```

Note: This method will return a int value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just told the URL, but you not called it..  solution is use $.ajax of jquery and call the action methods

```
function setrownumJQ() {
    var rownum = 0;
    var url = '@Url.Action("method", "controller")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url


    }).done(function (data) {
        rownum = data
    });
    return rownum;
}
```

Comment: thanks Now i am able to call the controller method, but i am not able to get the value from that.Here my method in controller  public See my method in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should not contain any methods or functionality except for actions. If you wish to pass data from (for example) the database to the view, your fetch functionality should be written in the Model class and passed in the action of your page as follows:

```
public ActionResult index() {
    ViewData["KEY"] = MyValue;
    ...
}
```