# How do I use a Button(Non Submit) Click Event to call a method on my Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I feel ridiculous asking this question but here goes, I am trying to make a very simple ASP.NET MVC 5 app.  My first of it's kind.  I want to have a button that when clicked does something but doesn't change the user's view or at most returns a "Email has been submitted" message.

My problem is I can't figure out how to wire a button to an "event" or "action" that doesn't change the view(i.e. using `@Html.ActionLink()`) or is a Submit button.  Every example I find is also of a Submit button.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT

This is still not working for me.  I'll post my code below.  My effort is based on what was said here and on the linked post.  Also, FYI, I can make it work with `@Html.ActionLink("link text", "actionname") but that appears as a link and I am trying to use a "Button".

*Index.cshtml*

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";  
}

<div class="hero-unit">
    <h3>Marketing & Communications Project Request Form</h3>   
    <p>User: <strong>@Context.User.Identity.Name</strong></p> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        @Html.ActionLink("Send Email", "SendEmail") @*this line works*@
        <input id="SendEmail" class="btn" type="button" value="SendEmail" /> @*this line does not

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text\javascript">
    $(function(){
        var url = '@Url.Action("SendEmail", "HomeController")';
        $("input#SendEmail").on('click', function() {                
            $.ajax({
                url: url    
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

*HomeController*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult SendEmail()
        {
            //Code to create and send email here

            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, say you have the following button, written in HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="MyButton" value="Click Me />
```

You can use jQuery to hook up to the `click` event:

```
$(function(){
    $("input#MyButton").on('click', function(){
    // Do what you want.
    });
});
```

If you use a HTML helper, such as `HTML.TextBoxFor()`, as long as you know the id of the `input` that is generated, you can use the same jQuery code to hook up the `click` event.

EDIT:

You can place that jQuery code either in the view e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("input#MyButton").on('click', function(){
        // Do what you want.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Usually you find script code placed near the bottom of the view, but you can place it anywhere you like really.

Or you could place that jQuery in a separate JavaScript (*.js) file. Just make sure you add the following to the `<head>` section in `_Layout.cshtml`:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='@Url.Content("~Scripts/YourFile.js")' ></script>`

`_Layout.cshtml` is a master layout file that is used across your project (assuming you have picked one of the usual ASP.NET MVC project templates in Visual Studio).

EDIT:

Regards the jQuery reference, in `_Layout.cshtml` you can add this, if jQuery is not already referenced:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='@Url.Content("~Scripts/jquery.version.js")' ></script>`

Just replace the filename for the correct one you have. Now, things get interesting if your MVC app uses bundling. That's a bit out of my knowledge bank, so might be better to look at other SO questions that talk about CSS/JavaScript bundling in MVC apps.

Comment: maybe stating the obvious, but might be worth mentioning reference to Jquery, as in the page needs to reference it.

Comment: I am using cshtml, where would I put the jQuery function?  I had thought on the View but I'm guessing no....

Comment: @RefractedPaladin, I only meant for Jason to put in the reference in case you, or other readers were not familiar with Jquery or the `$()` syntax in the answer.

Comment: @christiandev Hey, no worries, I understood just wanted to poke fun.  Should have used a self depreciating smile tag so my intent was obvious.

Comment: A follow up question....I have a method in my Controller, SendEmail(), how do I call that from inside the javascript function?

Comment: Here's one example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399808/how-can-i-call-a-controller-method-from-view

Answer (score 3):

You could simply achieve with this below sample code using jQuery ajax(post) call

```
<a id="btn-send-mail">SendEmail</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-send-mail').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var emailData={};
    emailData.toMail='sample@testmail.com';

    $.post('/Mail/Send/',{data:emailData}, function(result){
       if(result.status==true){
       alert('Email submitted successfully');
    }});//end of post
   });//end of click
 });//end of ready
```

Controller code

```
public class MailController
{
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult Send(Email obj)
  {
    //Code for sending email
    return Json(new {status=true});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use normal jquery call you can take advantage of Razor @Ajax.ActionLink.

You just set up the link like a normal Html.ActionLink and then create a controller action that sends your email, since this call is asynchronous it wont refresh the page.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Send Email", // <-- Text to display
     "SendEmail", // <-- Action Method Name
     new AjaxOptions
     {
        UpdateTargetId="", // <-- Used if you want to update up, DOM element ID to update
        HttpMethod = "GET" // <-- HTTP method
     })
```

I would recomend doing the jquery way but here is an [example](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2011/04/26/howto-ajax-actionlink-asp-net-mvc-3/) using Ajax.ActionLink